# Plural of “lemma”?

Tags: grammatical-number, writing

*Lemma* is the singular form. What is the more correct plural form of *lemma*: *lemmata* or *lemmas*? What word should I choose for scientific article?

Comment: Why the downvote? Seems harsh when lemma has an irregular plural as well as lemmas.

Comment: @TheMathemagician The downvote is automatically given for a general reference closure (I believe). Also, the question shows no research effort.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The plural of [lemma](http://i.word.com/idictionary/lemma) is lemmata or lemmas. Both are acceptable.

As a general note, the best way to find a plural is to look up the singular form in a dictionary. If there is a plural it will be listed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the English plural "lemmas" or the Greek plural "lemmata", but you cannot use "lemma" as a plural.

Comment: I've never seen lemmata used, and for comparison, I've seen the plurals stigmata, schemata, and stomata. I've also read a lot of mathematical papers. I'd stick with lemmas.